# What screen size to use in Unity3d for I phone and iPad

Tags: iphone, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a game for iPhone, iPad and Android in unity3d. The camera is looking top down. I have created a plane with texture of the ground. Now I want to place the camera such that the game area acquires full screen on the iPhone. Say if the size of iphone screen is 320x480 how will I calculate where to place the camera and plane in Unity 3d environment.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to make a 2D game.  You don't calculate it it that way. You have to use 2DToolkit, or, Unity's new 2D systems.  This is also true if you're going for a "pixel perfect" look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you have build your project to iPhone the aspect ratio drop down list of the [game view](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Learning%20the%20Interface.html) control bar changes according to your build settings. If for instance iOS is set as target, you will find entries like *iPhone Wide*, *iPhone Tall*, ...